# PHP string matching code for querying sql

Tags: php, sql, regex

I am trying to write a PHP code to query the following values.

Consider the expression NAME like \"$string\" where,

```
$string should match,
ABC,        //ABC can be followed by any characters (including special character)
ABCdef      //ABC can be followed by any characters (including special character)
ABC         //ABC followed by ONE Space
ABC df      //ABC SPACE followed by anything
def ABC sda //ABC being start of a word
ABC         //Just ABC
```

i.e. ABC should be the beginning of the string and should not be between any characters.

[edit]:
I tried something with wildcard characters like,

```
where $name like \"%$string%\" or like \"%string %\"
```

But it does not work.As I am new to PHP and regular expressions, can you help me in coming up with a solution.

Comment: Please explain this example `def ABC sda` does that mean that "ABC" can be at middle

Comment: yes, abc can be in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
/(^|\s)ABC/
```

We check for "Start of string" (^) or Whitespace (\s) followed by ABC

**Edit**

Borrowing from @rodneyrehm, you might be looking for the SQL, not the PHP regex - in this case you need

```
... WHERE name RLIKE '(^|\\s)ABC'
```

or without a regex

```
... WHERE (name LIKE 'ABC%' OR name LIKE '% ABC%')
```

Comment: i think he just wants `/^ABC.*/`. "ABC should be the beginning of the string"

Comment: But he also has `def ABC sda //ABC being start of a word`

Answer (score 1):

Are you, by any chance, looking for the wildcard?

```
WHERE name LIKE "ABC%"
```

See [String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html) or [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) if you truly need that.